# Ext.js 4.2 tabpanel header and body is misplaced when Browsers are zoomed

Tags: extjs, html-table

Not just zoomed, zoom in.

normal:
[image]

zoomed:
[image]

zoom in:
[image]

When there are many columns, he is very obvious. So is there any good hack?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [link](https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?340225-The-columns-in-grid-list-body-is-not-exactly-aligned-with-their-headers-in-Ext-Grid&p=1180844&viewfull=1#post1180844)

I'm mentioning what this user said in sencha forum, and I agree with him on this:

> This is a bug in Chrome that is reproducible outside the ExtJS framework.
>
> If you load the following HTML code in your browser, the cells align neatly. If you use browser zoom, they don't.
>
> The problem occurs when the cell width in pixels is floating point (non-int) after zooming. Chrome rounds the first-half cell widths down, and the last-half cell widths up.
>
> E.g. if the calculated width is 24.3333px, the first two-third of columns is 24px, the last third of columns is 25px. So if we have 54 columns, at Column 36, we are off by 12 pixels, or half a column.
>
> The ExtJS framework cannot do anything against this bug, unless Sencha knows a way to calculate the width AFTER zooming. I am not sure that it is possible to get the browser zoom level using javascript. However, I strongly believe that this is a problem the Chromium team has to fix.

I think there is still a workaround achievable through css. If you can, try using flex property to grid column in grid configuration. Calculate flex as = (given column width/sum of all column widths) and remove 'width' config at column level.

Flex actually sets width of each column in its CSS property after any layout change.